# basic line highcharts update using ajax

Tags: ajax, charts, highcharts

I want to implement basic line highchart (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic)
using ajax. chart values update through ajax.
please help me how I do it
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The highcharts website has an article about this here http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-live-data

This covers the basics of getting new data from the server using Ajax. If you want to add a new series to the chart, then you need to call

```
chart.addSeries(data)
```

Th is is documented here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()

Comment: In this article given chart for one series i want to dynamically add series in it. number of lines are not pacific.

Comment: thanx a lot Stevep its really helpfull for me

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at example where data is loaded by ajax
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax